# How to prepare a good response to referee reports when I have a weak reject and two accepts?

Tags: peer-review, conference, paper-submission

I received a weak reject, an accept and a strong accept from a top-tier conference in CS. So, I need to prepare a careful rebuttal response!
The problem is that the weak-reject reviewer did not ask any serious questions, and only stated that the novelty and contributions are limited and paper needs further polishing. But he stated a full confidence in his decision!

I already pointed out 3 main novel contributions in the paper. Should I just repeat (and rephrase) them in the response?

Personally, my feeling is that he did not try to go into the details of the work and responded based on some intuitions/feelings. I guess that based on his provided summary of the paper which is not exactly what i did.

It is also possible to send an additional confidential feedback to the conference program chair about the reviews' qualities or etc. but I'm not sure if that can be useful in this case?

Comment: Whi is PC ? Surely you are communicating with the editor?

Comment: @SolarMike: I mean the conference program chair assigned to my paper.